# How can I plot a pd.crosstab() table?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, crosstab

I have a dataframe just like any other, but with two categorical columns.

Just like this:

```
id    color      size
1     blue       M
2     red        S
3     red        M
4     blue       S
5     yellow     L
6     red        L
```

And I have the distribution table:

```
pd.crosstab(df['color'],df['size'], margins=None)
```

Is there a way of plotting this? (Just like tableau or power BI would)

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['color'],df['size'], margins=None).plot.bar()`? or `plt.imshow(pd.crosstab(df['color'],df['size'], margins=None).plot.bar())`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't mention, but the first one I tried and the problem was the x axis, the plot isn't with its tick mark centered. It's very weird. The second one you mentioned didn't work

Comment: The plot looks as expected. Since there are 3 groups, the group is centered on the tick, even if a value from the group is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Though matplotlib and seaborn doesn't allow plotting crosstabs, you can use pandas plot for the same.
It would look something like this:

`color = ['blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red']`

`size = ['M','S','M','S','L','L']`

`df = pd.DataFrame((color, size), index=['color','size']).T`

[Crosstab plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfelO.png)